# MS SQL Server installation fails with error message

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

I am trying to install SQL Server (tried all 2012 Developer edition, Web edition, Standard edition, Express and also tried all 2014 versions). Each time it is failing with the following error message

```
> (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: PerfCounter calling lodctr: 'C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS12\MSSQL\Binn\perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS12sqlctr.ini'
> (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: Prompting user if they want to retry
> this action due to the following failure: (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12
> Slp: ---------------------------------------- 
>(01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12
> Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in
> outermost to innermost order (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: Inner
> exceptions are being indented (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: (01)
> 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: Exception type:
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException (01) 2016-08-05
> 13:25:12 Slp: Message: (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: The system cannot
> find the file specified. (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp:  Slp:
> WatsonData =
> SQLCTR110.DLL@OpenSQLPerformanceData@CollectSQLPerformanceData@CloseSQLPerformanceData
> (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: DisableRetry = true (01) 2016-08-05
> 13:25:12 Slp: Inner exception type:
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp:
> Message: (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: The system cannot find the file
> specified. (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp:
> HResult : 0x80004005 (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: Error : 2 (01)
> 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: Stack: (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.LoadPerformanceCounter(String
> symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName) (01) 2016-08-05
> 13:25:12 Slp: at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounterCore(String
> libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction,
> String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String
> counterPrefixServiceName) (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp: at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounter(String
> libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction,
> String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String
> counterPrefixServiceName) (01) 2016-08-05 13:25:12 Slp:
> ---------------------------------------- (01) 2016-08-05 13:52:56 Slp: User has chosen to cancel this action (01) 2016-08-05 13:52:56 Slp:
> Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during
> timing ConfigNonRC and scenario ConfigNonRC. (01) 2016-08-05 13:52:56
> Slp: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified.". How did you download the installer? What have you tried? Are you running an AntiVirus, which may need to be disabled during install?

Comment: What is the OS version you are trying to install this on?

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire directory of logging done by the installer. If you are getting this from the graphical popup try looking in the \Setup Bootstrap folder under your installation of Sql Server. This is created whether it succeeds or not. The path is something like so...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log

In there you will find logs in separate folders by date and time. Like so..

\20160502_124028

Start with the Detail.txt log going all the way to the bottom and work your way up looking for anything with the word 'error' in it. That should give you more information about what is happening.

Also, I do see an access violation in the middle of your stack. That is:
HResult : 0x80004005

Hi Sofia,
     The detail.txt is a good place to start. It does refer to the file that was inaccessable. It is: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS12\MSSQL\Binn\perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS12sqlctr.ini" at the very beginning of the stack.

Whether or not this is the issue with the other editions of Sql Server you attempted to install I couldn't say. However if you aren't logged in as local Administrator while trying the install you should log in with the local Administrator account and retry the install.

Comment: The above error is from detail.txt but I am not able to determine which file is not found. I downloaded the installer from msdn.

Comment: Thanks for the direction to the access violation issue. I edited permissions to the file and all folders above it and I am logged in as local administrator but I keep getting the same message.

Comment: I also noticed that the error message mentions the dll which I cannot see in the installation directory PerfCounter Library file name: perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS2-sqlctr11.0.2100.60.dll. I am not sure where this dll is supposed to be found or is it possible to install sql server without performance counter